# Azure Boards - Display Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile, azure-boards

We have our Azure Boards (Project associated with Agile Process) defined as Feature >Epic >Tasks >User Story.

In our Azure Boards (Boards >Board), it displays only the Epic and Feature. It does not display tasks Underneath and user stories unless we go inside the Individual Epic.

Only after we are inside the Feature/Epic it shows the Child Items associated with it.

I want to have complete hierarchy to be displayed on my Sprint view and Board view.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct parent-child relationship of work items on Agile Process should be:
**`Epic > Feature > User Story > Task`**.

[image]

If you do not follow this order when linking parent / child items, you may get some unexpected issues. Such as some items cannot display as normal.

So, you need to change to the correct order.