# Scheduled backlog items not appearing in planning pane nor sprint to which they have been allocated (Azure Boards)

Tags: azure-boards

I've followed the instructions(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops) to allocated backlog items to sprint but, although the iteration path has updated, they don't appear in either the planning pane not the Sprint view.

Any advice?

[Work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t1Z7.jpg) [Planning pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7MI0.jpg) [Sprint screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7kfY.jpg)

Comment: Which work item types are you using, and which template (Agile, CMMI, SCRUM)? They look like features and epics, which don't appear on boards. Boards are for stories, tasks and bugs. See the diagram in this answer for the hierarchy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016562/azure-boards-display-configuration

Comment: Good question, I just went with whatever was set up with the free version. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Now I just need to work out how to close thise question... :-'

Comment: You can answer it yourself, and then the answer will help others who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're using **epics** item types. Try to create child items (features and backlog items / user stories) and check if you can see them (after assigning sprint and iteration path).

Generally speaking, different item types behave differently across entire DevOps platform.